# gcloud builds submit substitutions not working properly. (ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT.)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I have the following config:

```
steps:
- name: 'alpine'
  args: ['echo', 'B: ${_BRANCH}', 'T: ${_TAG}', 'C => ${_CLIENT}']
```

If I run with:

```
gcloud builds submit --config=gcp/cloudbuild-main.yaml --substitutions _CLIENT='client',_BRANCH='branch',_TAG='tag' .
```

I get the following message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT: generic::invalid_argument: key in the template "_BRANCH" is not matched in the substitution data; substitutions = map[_CLIENT:client _BRANCH=branch _TAG=tag];key in the template "_TAG" is not matched in the substitution data; substitutions = map[_CLIENT:client _BRANCH=branch _TAG=tag];key "_CLIENT" in the substitution data is not matched in the template
```

If I declare the substitutions:

```
steps:
- name: 'alpine'
  args: ['echo', 'B: ${_BRANCH}', 'T: ${_TAG}', 'C => ${_CLIENT}']
substitutions:
  _BRANCH: b1
  _TAG: latest
  _CLIENT: c
```

It runs but the substitutions take only the first variable and other become values of it:

```
BUILD
Pulling image: alpine
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
Digest: sha256:21a3deaa0d32a8057914f36584b5288d2e5ecc984380bc0118285c70fa8c9300
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
docker.io/library/alpine:latest
B: b1 T: latest C => client _BRANCH=branch _TAG=tag
PUSH
DONE
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to reproduce your issue, but it is working fine for me. Can you check if you are in the right folder? Also check if the name of the cloudbuild file is right.

Comment: Yes, they are. CaioT answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a syntax nit in your command which should be resolved by:

```
gcloud builds submit --config=gcp/cloudbuild-main.yaml --substitutions=_CLIENT="client",_BRANCH="branch",_TAG="tag" .
```

After submitting the build:

> B: branch T: tag C => client

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values

Comment: That worked, thanks.